# How to remove negative times from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have created a dataframe in pandas that shows the calculations of total time taken to complete a work order. Due to human input error some time calculations come up as a negative time as you can see in line 30, even if i swapped am over to PM it would still give a false time as work time is between 07:30 - 16:00, it would be better to just ignore these times

```
Work Order  WorkType        AST                 AFT             comp_time
10  BAEBRO-898690   RM  1900-01-01 06:27:41 1900-01-01 08:05:28 01:37:47
13  BAEBRO-914693   RM  1900-01-01 08:30:00 1900-01-01 09:00:00 00:30:00
27  BAEBRO-898787   RM  1900-01-01 10:00:00 1900-01-01 10:30:00 00:30:00
30  BAEBRO-914680   RM  1900-01-01 14:32:08 1900-01-01 10:37:17 -1 days +20:05:09
37  BAEBRO-914660   RM  1900-01-01 10:47:39 1900-01-01 11:32:02 00:44:23`
```

my code to get to this result is:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import time
from datetime import timedelta
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib as plt

df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Nativ_Zero/Desktop/work data/July.xls')

df_work = df[['Work Order', 'WorkType', 'AST','AFT']]

df_work['AFT'] = pd.to_datetime(df_work['AFT'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
df_work['AST'] = pd.to_datetime(df_work['AST'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')

rm_work = df_work[df_work.WorkType == 'RM']


rm_work['comp_time'] = rm_work['AFT'] - rm_work['AST']
rm_work.head()
```

Comment: You can just filter out negative values: `rm_work = rm_work[rm_work.com_time>=0]`

Comment: I put this code in and get: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'com_time'

Comment: It's `comp_time`, @PaulLane.

Comment: apologies i should have noticed that. I now get: TypeError: cannot compare a TimedeltaIndex with type int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below piece of code will work for you:

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Nativ_Zero/Desktop/work data/July.xls')

df_work = df[['Work Order', 'WorkType', 'AST','AFT']]

df_work['AFT'] = pd.to_datetime(df_work['AFT'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')
df_work['AST'] = pd.to_datetime(df_work['AST'], format='%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')

rm_work = df_work[df_work.WorkType == 'RM']


rm_work['comp_time'] = rm_work['AFT'] - rm_work['AST']
rm_work = rm_work[rm_work.comp_time >= pd.Timedelta(0)]  # Filtering condition
rm_work.head()
```

You need to compare using appropiate dtypes, which is `Timedelta` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Use .apply() to check if the pandas time is negative (be sure to compare to pd.Timedelta(0) rather than just 0 as that will error out).  If negative, return a numpy NaN.  Finally, exclude rows with NaNs.

This will cause problems if you already have NaNs in your column and want to keep them! In that case, you could change the method to return something else and then exclude on that unique value.

```
def check_if_negative(pd_time):
    if pd_time >= pd.Timedelta(0): # positive time and 0 time
        return pd_time
    elif pd_time < pd.Timedelta(0): # negative time
        return np.NaN
    else:
        print(f'problem! {pd_time} has an issue') # quick error check

rm_work['comp_time'] = rm_work['AFT'] - rm_work['AST'] # create timedelta
rm_work['comp_time'] = rm_work.comp_time.apply(check_if_negative) # apply check to column

rm_work = rm_work.dropna(subset=['comp_time']) # delete rows with NaN
```